# Sharing session between Sails JS and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, sails.js

How to share Redis session between Sails JS and Spring Boot. sails.sid is generated by using secret key which is hashed. How do i decode that sails.sid at spring boot app ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get your question right.

1. Simpliest solution ( will fit in most cases) - by sharing the secret key (one you have in `config/session.js`) through Redis key value (could be done in `config/bootstrap.js`). If the Spring Boot have access to the Redis, it can recieve the key from it.
2. It could be recieved dynamically in deployment/startup process through env variable of by other means - for example pulled from some kind of configuration storage. This means Sails no longer hold it, and will recieve it on it's boot.
3. More complex, most secure solutions (only really meaningful and useful in certain circumstances, and probably not for this case, but still such option exist) is RPC through TCP/TLS.